# How do I make Matplotlib graph more spaced out?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I am using pandas to generate a dataframe. Then I am using matplotlib to generate a graph from this dataframe.

It is hard to see the points all the way on the right. How do I make it more spaced out?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVsyr.png]

I would like it to be wider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to change the size of the plot try..

```
df.plot(figsize=(20,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about what you mean by "wider"? You can make the horizontal axis wider, but the big gap from 2008 to 2010 will still dominate. You can make a second plot just zooming in on 2013. Anything that scales that part of the axis disproportionately will be a no-no.

I would recommend just getting rid of the lines connecting the points and plotting your symbols with no outline, and with a bit of transparency (`alpha=.6` perhaps), and it will look a lot better.

Comment: I mean just streching it horizontally. Perhaps showing all the months and giving each month a width of like 1/2 inch or something. I dont like that in 2013 all the dots are on top of each other.

Comment: That will be the exactly same as just setting your figure size to be really wide...  `plt.figure(1, figsize=(10, 4))` The points are on top of each other because their underlying data overlap. If you make each month half an inch, then each year will be 6 inches and your plot will be 3 feet wide.